# How to add a jquery listener?

Tags: jquery

I have a list sorter plugin that is sorting just fine but the filter function is not working. I think it is because the filter buttons are not directly adjacent the list that needs to be filtered. How would I add a listener for the div that contains the list to be filtered?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/S9vU2/

This may be a solution but not sure how to implement it with the existing jquery:

```
$('#random-search-field').keyup(function() {
    list.search($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: your filter buttons are working for me. I added an alert in them and they are triggering.

Comment: when you click on filter the items go away. it should only show the item that is filtered. eg. click on NLI and the NLI item should be the only one showing.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions you are looking for `category` but you do not have that in the `options` list. I changed `category` to `Type` and it seems to be filtering correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/S9vU2/3/

```
$('#filter-LPO').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.values().Type == "LPO") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

jsfiddle seems slow right now so let it load completely.